# Strange issue on retrieving a proportion of files from a directory: No such file or directory error in python

Tags: python, file, directory, training-data

I know this may be a repetitive question but it has a special point which i can't find out.
 I'm trying to retrieve files from a directory in my python application. The function below retrieves a proportion of files based on `testOrTrain` variable. Here is my code:

```
def get_files_in_dir(directory,trainOrTest):
    file_names_list = []
    for file_name in glob.glob(directory):
        file_names_list += [file_name]

   #1 for train_data and 0 for test_data
    if trainOrTest == 1:
      proportion = len(os.listdir(directory))*65/100
      return file_names_list[:int(proportion)]
    elif trainOrTest == 0:
      proportion = len(os.listdir(directory))*35/100
      return file_names_list[int(proportion):]
    # return file_names_list
```

And here is the function in which i use it:

```
def training_data():
   for i in range(1,2):
     p = 'C'+'%.2d' % i
     file_path = os.path.join('ohsumed-all',str(p),'*')
     for file in get_files_in_dir(file_path,1):
        file_data = get_text_file_data(file)
        print(file_data)
```

This code gives me the error "No such file or directory". The strange thing about this code is that when i delete the `if` parts and just simply return files_names_list(the part of code in the comment), it works fine.
Does somebody know what is happening here?

By the way, i'm working on wsl(ubuntu)

Comment: What are you passing in for `directory`? Does it contain any glob wildcards?

Comment: @samiravs Thanks for editing the question. As I suspected, your `directory` string contains a glob wildcard - the `*` at the end. `os.listdir` doesn't handle wildcards - it's exclusively handled by glob. That's why you're getting the error. Why do you even need `os.listdir` in the first place? You already know how many files are in the directory - it's the length of `file_names_list`.

Comment: @PaulM. But the ```proportion``` variable returns a true value. and to answer your question, i need to retrieve the number of files in a folder to split them into two parts: train and test files

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You said "proportion variable returns a true value". I don't know what you mean by this. If `os.listdir` does not throw an exception, `proportion` could only ever be a float, not a boolean. And yes, I know what your code is supposed to do - but I'm asking you: Why do you need `os.listdir`? The only reason you're using it is to figure out how many files are in the directory - but you don't need to do that because you already know how many files are in the directory! `len(file_names_list)` is equal to the number of files in the directory, so you don't need `os.listdir`.

Comment: @PaulM. I got you. I don't know why i have done such a silly thing here to get numbrer of files!!!! :). Thanks a lot. By the way replacing ```len(os.listdir(directory))``` with ```len(glob.glob(directory))``` also solved the error. Thanks again